# How cañ one increase power from 1.5 kw to 20kw using gears

Tags: classical-mechanics

Types of gears to be used
Number of gears required
Sizes of gears required

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By using gears, you can increase torque, but not power

Comment: How can I increase power using gears

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. That would violate the conservation of energy.

Comment: What is the best way to increase power using gears

Comment: @Joshua it is not possible. That would violate the conservation of energy. I don’t know how to be more clear than that. It cannot be done